# nginx try_files location Configuration?

Tags: php, nginx, slim

I am in the process of writing a directory listings script in Slim 3 Framework. I am having a problem that Slim 3 is not getting the request for a file download when it exists due to the 'try_files' directive in the configuration. Once I change the order of the 'try_files' it then fails to process any .php file for that matter.

Here is the current block of the configuration:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

this was the tried configuration (and failed - it would serve up a .bin file with the contents of my index.php instead of processing it):

```
location / {
        try_files /index.php$is_args$args $uri;
    }
```

Ultimately, I want my Slim 3 script to capture the request and do something with it instead of simply serving it up by the web server.

Answer (score 0):

If I rewrite all files to the index.php page as a parameter, I get my desired output. Here is the nginx configuration code:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
}
```